# Wordpress add query var to URL on load

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I´m currently developing a wordpress site that links to different products based on the users country. I´m using the GeoIP detection api the detect the country by the IP address and then return the country code.
I have a query var called "country". I want to set the country query var equal to the returned country code on page load, but i really don't know how.

Comment: Silly question:  Why do you want to set the query var before page load?  Generally speaking query_vars contain data pulled from the database.  So setting something in the database before the page loads would mean setting the query var and then querying the db _again_ after saving the data to the database.  Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_query_arg

to add a query variable. I am assuming that you are redirecting to another page after page load.

```
add_query_arg( 'country', 'DE', 'http://example.com' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/